# C structures declarations

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have a problem with declaring structures in C.
I need to make a NetworkNode that will have an array of ConnectionNode and the connection node, as you know this results in error:

error: field "target" has incomplete type

What are the solutions for this problem?

btw. Here is the code:

```
struct ConnectionNode
{
    char* name;
    struct NetworkNode target;
};

typedef struct ConnectionNode ConnectionObject;

struct NetworkNode
{
    char* name;
    int i;
    struct ConnectionNode connections[10];
};

typedef struct NetworkNode NetworkObject;
```

Comment: `typedef struct NetworkNode NetworkObject` at the beginning.Then declare the the structure later.

Comment: You may want to have a look there : [forward declaration C  struct][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026655/struct-forward-declaration-fails-compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very beginning of your program, add forward declaration for `NetworkNode`:

```
struct NetworkNode;
```

This allows compiler to understand what is `NetworkNode` and break that catch-22 that in definition of `ConnectionNode` you need to mention `NetworkNode` and vice versa.

**UPDATE**:
Also, you need to change your definition of ConnectionNode:

```
...
struct NetworkNode target;
...
```

to use pointer instead:

```
struct NetworkNode *target;
```

Without this, compiler would not know how how much memory to allocate for NetworkNode (even with forward declaration). Pointers, on other hand, always have the same size.

Comment: Well, I did that just now, but it's not the solution. I still got the error.

Comment: he is NOT using a Pointer!

Comment: @PeterMiehle: yes, you are right - thanks! I have updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: Well I tried to avoid pointers but it seems It's not possible. Anyway after changing type for pointer and fixing some of my functions all went OK! Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but try using pointer here and make forward reference by declaring the structure before using it. Add pointer to structure `NetworkNode` ( Ex. *target) so that compiler reserve the memory of 2 bytes for pointer which is referencing to `NetworkNode` structure. But when you declare `struct NetworkNode target`, compiler doesn't know the size and it throws error "incomplete type"

```
struct NetworkNode;
struct ConnectionNode
{
    char* name;                      //pointer 2 bytes
    struct NetworkNode *target;      //pointer 2 bytes
};                                  //total 4 bytes reserved
```

and when you do like,

```
struct NetworkNode;
struct ConnectionNode
{
    char* name;                      //pointer 2 bytes
    struct NetworkNode target;       //unknown size of target as it is not YET defined
};                                  //total size: unknown (error: incomplete type)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you type

```
struct NetworkNode target;
```

the compiler has to know the size of the struct to allocate enough Memory for target;

normally one would use

```
struct NetworkNode *target;
```

to reference another Object (with separate malloc) and that can be done as forward declaration.

The Problem with your declaration is:

```
struct ConnectionNode {
  struct NetworkNode target;
}
struct NetworkNode {
  struct ConnectionNode connection;
}
```

is, that the compiler is not able to evaluate the size for one Object of type struct NetworkNode.